# To create another mouse cursor in VC++ MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Am struck up with a problem.. Basically in my project am having two windows. when certain condition is satisfied, i need to do operation on two windows simultaneously at the same time. Initially, I used to do like this First do operation on first window once finished then perform operation on second window & the  result is there is delay between these two operations since it has to happen at the same time same movement without delay..

So i thought to create another mouse cursor.. I mean one original mouse cursor & another Programmatically created cursor, So when condition satisfied Original cursor can operate on first window & programmatically created can operate on second window.. with this both operation can happen simultaneously at the same time..
Please can anyone guide/suggest me Is it possible to create another cursor ? If so, please suggest me... If not, Give me any ideas how to accomplish this task..

Thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have two cursors.

If you're just moving the windows, try [DeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); otherwise you could try using [SetRedraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btaacw58%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Then at least they will *look* as if they are moving / changing at the same time...

Comment: Ok...Thank you liam.. Thanks for the suggestion :)