# How to simulate mouse move in multiple windows at the same time?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse, mousemove, simulate

I need to simulate mouse move inside of windows under Win 7. Usually i would use `SendInput()`. But it can simulate mose moving only at the one window at the time. I need to simulate mouse moving at the multiple windows at the time.

Is this even possible? And how?

Comment: This has already been answered
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603369/to-create-another-mouse-cursor-in-vc-mfc)

Comment: There is only one mouse cursor.  It sounds like you have a solution in mind (which isn't possible to implement); what is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Eric Brown, i'm developing a multi-process program. Each process simulates some user actions inside of it's window. About 15-20 processes working at each moment of time while program runs. Also every process should simulate mouse moving.

Comment: I guess you'll need to define what you mean by "simulate mouse moving". Do you understand that the system has only one cursor?

Comment: Well, the process should "think" that the cursor is over it's window, that it changes it's position and never quit it's window region. Window procedure should react in appropriate way. How about `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648394.aspx) function is the API function that allows you to modify the location of the cursor.

Comment: `SetCursorPos` Moves the cursor to the specified screen coordinates on the screen, I doubt it will not able to move to 2 different coordinates at same time.

Comment: @Prakash Nothing can do that!

Comment: I am just curious that how would `SetCursorPos` answers the OP question.

Comment: @Prakash I guess you understand the question differently from how I understand it. There's only one cursor. And `SetCursorPos` is the way to move it. That's all there is.